# How to integrate C++ library when its package is not named

Tags: c++, cmake, build

C++ and CMake newbie question regarding how to integrate a third-party library into my own code. I'm trying to add Datadog metrics to C++ application. The [officially-endorsed library](https://github.com/BoardiesITSolutions/cpp-datadogstatsd) doesn't state how it can be integrated. I imagine it should tell me how to import it like this:

```
find_package(<PACKAGE> REQUIRED)
add_executable(foobar src/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(foobar PUBLIC ${<PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES>})
target_link_libraries(foobar ${<PACKAGE_LIBRARIES>})
```

This is my understanding of how to integrate a third-party library (don't you wish there is "pip" in C++?). But the names in <> are not provided in the README. I certainly don't have to do it like this as long as I can use CMake. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just put the folder in your source tree, use `add_subdirectory` and `include_directories`, then like your executable against the output. No need for `find_package` unless you installed that lib using a package manager

Comment: The `CMakeLists.txt` file the lib provides is severely lacking.Also taking a look at the headers indicates that it won't be possible to use build a usable .dll (at least there is nothing that could be used to insert dllimport/export statements. Assuming you know where the lib is installed though, I'd recommend adding an imported library via `add_library` and set the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` target property. In addition to this the include directory via `target_include_directories` using `INTERFACE` "visibility". Using `include_directories` is actually not a good idea, apply to all targets in a dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution is to fetch this library directly and do `add_subdirectory`. But this requires cmake >= 3.11.

Create dir `cmake` and file `cmake/cpp-datadogstatsd.cmake`

`cpp-datadogstatsd.cmake`:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
        datadogstatsd
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/BoardiesITSolutions/cpp-datadogstatsd
        # try v1.1.0.5 if this does not work
        GIT_TAG        1.1.0.5
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(datadogstatsd)
if(NOT datadogstatsd_POPULATED)
    message(STATUS "Downloading datadogstatsd...")

    FetchContent_Populate(datadogstatsd)
    add_subdirectory(${datadogstatsd_SOURCE_DIR} ${datadogstatsd_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

Then, include this cmake file, and link `DataDogStatsD_static` to your lib/exe:

```
include(cmake/cpp-datadogstatsd.cmake)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test DataDogStatsD_static)
```

Comment: Thank you @warchantua! That makes sense. I wonder if `DataDogStatsD_static` is created automatically by including "cmake/cpp-datadogstatsd.cmake"?

Comment: It is created by the author of that lib. Try to read their root CMakeLists.txt and you will find it.